# Javascript - get the first false value time and show it every second until value changed to true

Tags: javascript

I have one function named `showData` that continuously show list of array every second. In object array, have a property named `value` that contain only boolean/true or false.

If the property `value` is false, i want to get the datetime and show it every second. Just at the first time i get the `value` is false.

Code :

```
const showData = () => {
    const datetime = new Date();
    const dt = datetime + '';

    const lists = [
        {
            name: 'peter',
            value: false,
            datetime: dt
        },
        {
            name: 'john',
            value: true,
            datetime: dt
        }
    ]

    const list_false = lists.filter((list) => {
        return list.value === false
    })
    console.log(list_false);

    const list_true = lists.filter((list) => {
        return list.value === true
    })
    console.log(list_true);
}

const interval = setInterval(showData, 1000);
```

The code above show results like this :

```
// first
[ { name: 'peter', value: false, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]

// second
[ { name: 'peter', value: false, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:23 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:23 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]

// third
[ { name: 'peter', value: false, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:24 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:24 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
```

At the three results above shows different datetime every second for `value: false`. I mean how can just show the first datetime every second until the `value: true`?

Results i want :

```
// first
[ { name: 'peter', value: false, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]

// second
[ { name: 'peter', value: false, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:23 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]

// third
[ { name: 'peter', value: false, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:24 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
```

And if the value changed to true `value: true` the result back to normal again with real datetime :

```
// first
[ { name: 'peter', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]

// second
[ { name: 'peter', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:23 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:23 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]

// third
[ { name: 'peter', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:24 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
[ { name: 'john', value: true, datetime: 'Mon Mar 12 2018 01:12:24 GMT+0700 (WIB)' } ]
```

Can anyone help me to do that?

**Updated code**:

```
const showData = () => {
    const datetime = new Date();
    const dt = datetime + '';

    const lists = [
        {
            name: 'peter',
            value: Math.random() >= 0.5,
            datetime: dt
        },
        {
            name: 'john',
            value: Math.random() >= 0.5,
            datetime: dt
        }
    ]

    const list_false = lists.filter((list) => {
        return list.value === false
    })
    console.log(list_false);

    const list_true = lists.filter((list) => {
        return list.value === true
    })
    console.log(list_true);
}

const interval = setInterval(showData, 1000);
```

With code above, it will show randomly true or false every 1 second.

**New update :**

These last few days i really confused to combine the simple example code above with the real code.

I just try to create minimal code example so nothing a lot of code i post in here but after the minimal code example works good and i want to combine with the real code, the result is not same.

So i tried to create a new minimal example code.

This is the new minimal example code :

```js
const lists = [
  {
    name: 'peter',
    value: false,
    datetime: (new Date().toString())
  },
]

const showData = () => {
  const array = [];

  const object = {
    name2: lists[0].name,
    value2: lists[0].value = Math.random() >= 0.5,
    datetime2: lists[0].datetime
  }
  array.push(object);

  const datetime3 = (new Date().toString());
  array.reduce((acc, x) => {
    if(!x.value2) return acc.concat(x);
    x.datetime2 = datetime3;
    return acc.concat(x);
  },[])
  console.log(array);
}

const interval = setInterval(showData, 1000);

const stopToSee = setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 20000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If we try to run the new minimal example code above, we can see if the `value2` past 3 conditions (false -> true -> false). Datetime at the first false condition is equal with datetime at the third false condition.

How to make datetime at the first false condition different with the third false condition. I mean, the third false condition show the current datetime at the third false condition, not the first false condition datetime.

Note : I really need to create new `object` in `showData` which will continuously show the data every 1 second, because in the real code i used promise to generate new value. So after the new value is generated, i must create new object with the new value inside it.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

The new minimal example code result :

```
// first false condition, time shown 00:00:00
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// second true condition
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:02 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:03 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// third false condition, time shown 00:00:00
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
```

Result i want :

```
// first false condition, time shown 00:00:00
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// second true condition
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:02 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:03 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// third false condition, time shown 00:00:04
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:04 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:04 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
const lists = [ // one single instance of lists
  {
    name: 'peter',
    value: false,
    date: new Date() + ''
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    value: true,
    date: new Date() + ''
  }
]

const func = (function showData (lists) {
    return () => {
      const datetime = new Date();
      const dt = datetime + '';

      // changing only value property
      lists[0].prevValue = lists[0].value;
      lists[1].prevValue = lists[1].value;
      lists[0].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;
      lists[1].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;

      lists.reduce((acc, x) => {
        if(!x.value && !x.prevValue) return acc.concat(x);
        x.date = dt;
        return acc.concat(x);
      },[])

      const list_false = lists.filter((list) => {
          return list.value === false
      })
      console.log(list_false);

      const list_true = lists.filter((list) => {
          return list.value === true
      })
      console.log(list_true);
    }
})(lists)

const interval = setInterval(func, 1000);

const stopToSee = setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 10000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can change your `list` values dynamically and your function your work accordingly.

Comment: Note the IIFE here is pretty much useless since `lists` is going to be the same object in or outside the function, passing it through an IIFE does not make a new object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have problem if the value is changed. first condition the `value` is false = no problem. second condition the `value` change to true = no problem again but after that at third condition if the` value` back to false, the `datetime` show the first datetime condition. I mean, how if the third condition back to false then the datetime show the current datetime at the third condition, not the first condition datetime.

Comment: @Ras the way this code were implemented, once you get value back to false then your date will be the last processed when value was true

Comment: @guijob i already update the code with random value and will generate random true or false, can you show me how it works with the updated random value?

Comment: @Ras, that's because you are recreating your `lists` with new date values everytime you call your function. you should hold one single instance and then change only your `value` value. i've edited my answer in order to reproduce this behavior

Comment: @guijob I already create a new minimal example code, you can check it above. I hope you can help me, I apologize for having troubled you.

Comment: @Ras I didn't get it, do you want false values acting like true ones?

Comment: @guijob i want false values show the first false datetime value every second until the false value change to true value. After the true value change again to false value, i want this false value show the current false datetime every second until it change to true, not showing the first false datetime value. I already update my post with example result and result i want.

Comment: @Ras for this, I'd recommend you to store previous value `value` before to generate a new one. I've edited my original answer in order to add that expected behavior

Comment: @guijob Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your list within the function. So each time the function is called that list is not the same as in the previous call. If you want the objects in the list maintain state between calls you need to define them outside the function and only update them when you intend to

```js
const lists = [{
  name: 'peter',
  value: false,
  datetime: (new Date()).toString()
},
{
  name: 'john',
  value: true,
  datetime: (new Date()).toString()
}];

const showData = () => {
  const datetime = new Date();
  const dt = datetime + '';
  const list_false = [], list_true = [];
  
  //Use a single loop to split the objects into
  //different arrays.
  lists.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.value){
      //if it's true update the time
      item.datetime = dt;
      list_true.push(item);
    } else {
      list_false.push(item);
    }
  });
  
  console.log(list_false[0].datetime);
  console.log(list_true[0].datetime);
}

const interval = setInterval(showData, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have problem if the value is changed. first condition the `value` is false = no problem. second condition the `value` change to true = no problem again but after that at third condition if the` value` back to false, the `datetime` show the first datetime condition. I mean, how if the third condition back to false then the datetime show the current datetime at the third condition, not the first condition datetime.

Comment: @Ras your updated code does implement either answers code

Comment: Mr. Patrick Evans, my updated code just generate dynamic value true or false, but not get the first false value time and show it every second until value change to true.

Comment: Mr. Patrick Evans, i already create a new minimal example code, you can check it above. I hope you can help me, I apologize for having troubled you.